# Perl program for palindrome in paragraph

Tags: arrays, algorithm, perl, bioinformatics, palindrome

I want to write a perl program for finding the number of palindromes in a paragraph.
But here I have to do it using an array. Please help.

Comment: What is meant with "paragraph" and "array". Please explain!

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail? Looping over half the array and checking that array(*i*) is equal to array(*max*-*i*) would seem straightforward both conceptually and algorithmically.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but you need to clarify. "Never Odd Or Even" is a palindrome that's in the middle of the paragraph of this comment.

Comment: Yes, Its for both odd and even , here paragraph means more than 3-4 sentences assume it and I want to take all those in an array and find the palindromes (both odd and even)

Comment: @Rajkishore90 is there any reason to even do those challenges if you don't at least try for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`perlretut - Recursive patterns`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

It includes an example of testing for palindromes that you can no doubt adapt to your purposes, whatever they are exactly:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pp = qr/^(\W* (?: (\w) (?1) \g{-1} | \w? ) \W*)$/ix;

for $s ( "saippuakauppias", "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!" ){
    print "'$s' is a palindrome\n" if $s =~ $pp;
}
```

Outputs:

```
'saippuakauppias' is a palindrome
'A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!' is a palindrome
```